# Laravel collection get occurrences of a MtoM relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

this is my situation:
I have a collection of products and i want all the categories of those products.
Between `Product` and `Category` there is a many-to-many relation already created, and i want to do something like this:

```
$prods = Product::where(something)->get();
$categories = $prods->categories();
```

But obviously this doesn't work, and i would avoid getting all categories for each products, and add it to a collection only if is not alredy in it... something like this:

```
select *
from categories join pivot on categories.id = pivot.id
where pivot.product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

where `1,2,3,4,5` are the ids of the products

Is there any way to do it without `QueryBuilder` (using `Eloquent`)?

Comment: This is isn't your situation

Comment: @Strawberry the Minimal Reproducible Example is the first 2 lines. i need to get all the categories of those products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a many-to-many relationship in your `Product` model

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

And then you can do this

```php
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

$prods = Product::with('categories')->findOrFail($ids);

$categories = $prods->flatMap->categories;
```

The `with` call eager loads your categories, and then you retrieve them easily + flatten (to avoid multi-dimensional collection) thanks to `flatMap` method.

Comment: is there any way to do it DB-side? like in the query showed?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `DB-side`? You asked for an Eloquent way

Comment: yes, but i mean something like "Category::whereIn($wines)" and so the computation to get the categories is done DB-side

Comment: thanks, but i want the opposite, given the products, i want the categories ahaha also, flatMap works only on many to many?

Comment: Edited, and no, `flatMap` is a method from Laravel Collections ( I used the higher-order proxy version in my answer https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#higher-order-messages ). When you use Eloquent, you retrieve `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instances which inherit from `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, that's why you can use it.

Comment: thank you, but i mean, but for example, if i have  a one to many between products and catgories, can i use flatMap also to get the distincted categories with no duplicates?

Comment: Yes you can, but you will get potential duplicates. You can do this to get unicity `$categories = $prods->flatMap->categories->unique->id;`